# Force PHP to execute include even if there is an error later in the script

Tags: php, parsing, include

I am trying to create a system where by adding one include, I can set PHP to display errors (the php.ini file prevents this). In other words:

```
<?php
    include "showerrors.php";
    // Produce Error
    ERROR;
?>
```

This would create a parse error and "showerrors.php" does not get executed, meaning that the error never gets shown. However, if "showerrors.php" does get executed, the error would be shown.

Comment: Then fix the parse error.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *parse error*, i.e. *invalid syntax*, then no code in the file will be executed because the file can't be parsed. That includes `include` statements. As simple as that, no way around it. It's not difficult to make sure your file has at least *correct syntax*, such tools are integrated into most editors and IDEs.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Notepad++ so I don't have anything to tell me I'm going wrong. That means that in some circumstances, when there is a typo in the code, I have nothing to tell me where I have gone wrong. This means that it could take hours to find.

Comment: Then either get a better editor or *look at your server's error logs*. The error is being reported *somewhere*. You can also always run your PHP files through the commandline `php` app for a syntax check. I'd be surprised if Notepad++ didn't have a "Check PHP syntax" command somewhere.

Comment: Notepad++ is just a text editor, it has lots of plugins available, but I haven't looked through them yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should do exactly the opposite - in showerrors.php turn on error reporting and include the requested file (you can redirect all requests to showerrors.php via mod_rewrite / whatsever supported by the server and then include the requested file)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm relatively new to server side configuration, please could you go into more detail about how your solution works?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a parse error, PHP can't execute. Asking if you can force PHP to continue to execute after an error is like asking if you can force a car to start even if the engine is blown - it just can't happen.